# TailwindCSS colors don't update colors

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make active buttons on the navbar so when an section is active it's highlighted.
For the colors I'm using custom colors and to change the state I'm using useState.
The problem is the buttons are working fine but Tailwind doesn't "stick" the active color the buttons.In the browser console i can see that useState updates the class text but nothing really shows in reality.

The Tailwind config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primery':'#01092E',
        'secondary': '#011749',
        'accent':'#6948B9',
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "hero-pattern": "url('/src/assets/herobg.jpg')",
      },

      
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is my component code

```
<ul className="list-none hidden sm:flex justify-center gap-10">
          {navLinks.map((nav) => (
            <li
              key={nav.id}
              className={`text-white hover:text-accent cursor-pointer text-[18px] font-medium px-4 
              ${active === nav.title ? " text-accent " : " text-white "}`}
            >
              <Link
                to={nav.id}
                smooth={true}
                duration={500}
                offset={-80}
                onClick={() => setActive(nav.title)}
              >
                {nav.title}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are dynamically adding the `tailwindCSS` classes in the div. TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

```
`className={`text-white hover:text-accent cursor-pointer text-[18px] font-medium px-4 ${active === nav.title ? " text-accent " : " text-white "}`}
```

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Instead, you must include the full name of the class in your source code. You can return the full value by using a function like this

```
function  myDecoStyle(active) {
if(active === nav.title) 
   return "text-white hover:text-accent cursor-pointer text-[18px] font-medium px-4 text-accent ";
else 
   return "text-white hover:text-accent cursor-pointer text-[18px] font-medium px-4 text-white ";
}
```

where `active` is the state you are passing here.

By doing it this way, the entire string for every class is in your source code, so TailwindCSS will know to generate the applicable CSS.

And use it like

```
           <li
              key={nav.id}
              className={`${myDecoStyle(active)}`}
            >
            <Link
                to={nav.id}
                smooth={true}
                duration={500}
                offset={-80}
                onClick={() => setActive(nav.title)}
              >
                {nav.title}
              </Link>
            </li>
```

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Comment: Great explanation! ! ! I manage to fix my issue with removing the color from the class and just apply colors with the conditions

Comment: Glad I am able to help you 

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question but if the problem is that your dynamically added class isn't being registered it is becasue you need to add a safelist to your config file:

```
 safelist: [
   'text-accent',
    'text-white
]
```

[tailwind docs safe-listing](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

Comment: I can use the classes and the colors work everywhere else but when i try to update them with useState

Comment: Did you try what I showed? Or the link I sent? I could be mistaken, but I am pretty sure that is what you need

Comment: I did but it didn't fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i was passing the same color 2 times. Once in the className and once in the condition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).